# How can I resolve an invalid identifier on an Oracle DB query result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle DB and I need to list the number of departments per region in the region table.

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT r.region_id, COUNT(d.department_id) "Number of Department"
FROM region r, department d
WHERE r.region_id = d.region_id
GROUP BY r.region_id
```

I am getting the following error:

> "D", "region_id": invalid identifier

How can I correct this?

Edit 1 -

here are the tables from Departments to Regions

Departments Table 
Dept_id, Dept_name ,Manager_Id, Location_Id 

Locations Table 
Location_id, street_add, postal_code, city, state_province, country_id

Countries Table 
Country_Id, Country_name, Region_Id

Regions Table 
Region_Id, Region_Name

Comment: show tables structure

Comment: Obviously the table `department` has no `region_id`. Maybe you Need more tables to get from departments to regions. Locations? Countries?

Comment: On a side note: Don't use implicit comma-separated joins. They became deprecated in 1992. Use explicite joins instead (`FROM table 1 INNER JOIN table2 ...`).

Comment: I've already updated my post with the table structures.

@ThorstenKettner Okay I'll use that instead of a comma, I am just starting to learn Oracle as my Specialization.

Comment: So is your question answered by my comment above? You understand that you cannot join the departments with regions directly, but must use the other tables, too. So do you have any further question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join together all four of your tables, which intuitively makes sense to me from the point of this being an assignment.  Something along these lines should work:

```
SELECT r.region_id, COUNT(d.department_id) "Number of Department"
FROM department d INNER JOIN location l
    ON d.location_id = l.location_id
INNER JOIN country c
    ON l.country_id = c.country_id
INNER JOIN region r
    ON c.region_id = r.region_id
GROUP BY r.region_id
```

Comment: You can make this `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(d.department_id)`. There is no need to apply `DISTINCT` here.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I was struggling trying to visualize this, because for `country` or `location` we would almost certainly need `DISTINCT`.  I guess you're right if departments cannot be subdivided any further.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: I used your query edited some of it and got what I needed. Thank you guys.